# Could the earliest life on Earth have traveled through a wormhole billions of years ago into an alternate dimension and evolved independently?

Tags: alternate-worlds, astrophysics, prehistoric-times, wormholes

So it's fairly common knowledge that the first signs of life on Earth were in the Archean eon, when the crust started to cool and continents started to form. Life arose around 3.7ish billion years ago, either through abiogenesis or panspermia. From what I understand, these were micro-organisms that may have lived in deep sea hydrothermal vents.

Now, let's say it's around 3.5 billion years ago, and our little prokaryotes (hope I'm using the term correctly) are just chillin' around on a primordial earth. And then suddenly, a wormhole appears. Again, as far as I've researched, it's *theoretically* possible for naturally-occurring wormholes to appear and disappear at the Planck scale, as theorized by Leonard Susskind.

How, if we do a little bit of handwaving - could it be possible that a bigger wormhole appeared, and these early life-forms happened to travel through it to another Earth in a parallel dimension? Could they evolve independently on this alternate Earth, creating a wildly new and convergent evolutionary chain/biosphere etc?

I know this is VERY theoretical, but is it even within somewhat of a realm of possibility? Would it make more sense to jump forward a few million years so the life-forms have evolved a little bit, and have some form of rudimentary intelligence where they would go through the wormhole instead of being pulled into it?

Comment: We are a site to help people build consistent **ficitional** worlds. Your question almost sounds as if you ask if this could really have happened.

Comment: 'Is this theoretically possible' isn't really a world building question, and if answered 'yes' there's no end to the broadness and opinion-based answers.

Comment: You're actually asking TWO questions here, you should refine it to one or the other. Question 1 is: Could wormholes transport living microbes without killing them. Question 2 is: Could Earth-origin primordial life potentially survive somewhere else. The first is, in my opinion, completely opinion based and will probably get your post closed. The second is potentially answerable, so I'd suggest you edit your post to focus on that one.

Comment: Just to clarify, the Planck scale is around .00000000000000000000000000000000001 meters. A prokaryote is .000001 meters. The difference is a factor of *29*, or (roughly speaking) the difference between a single atom and the entire human body.

Comment: *"[Panspermia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panspermia) (from Ancient Greek* pan *meaning 'all', and* sperma *meaning 'seed') is the hypothesis that life exists throughout the Universe, distributed by space dust, meteoroids, asteroids, comets, planetoids, and also by spacecraft carrying unintended contamination by microorganisms. Distribution may have occurred spanning galaxies."* (Wikipedia, *s.v.* Panspermia) Wormholes are not needed when millions and millions of years are available to complete the journey.

Comment: @Halfthawed The OP did specify the wormhole transporting micro-organisms to an alternative Earth was larger than the Planck scale. I presume you mentioned the difference in 29 orders of magnitude for the benefit of those who are scale challenged.

Comment: @a4android That was my intention, yes, though looking back it's not very clear what I meant.

Answer (score 6):

The idea of using wormholes to travel to a parallel universe is currently 100% science fiction.  Yes, we have Tegmark's classification of multiverses which says something that we call "parallel universes" could exist.  However, we have absolutely no credible modeling to say whether or not a wormhole can reach to one or not.  Accordingly, the answer has to be "if its convenient for your story, go for it."

As for the survival of microbes, its highly likely they could survive in a "parallel" Earth.  In the early ecosystems, the environment was dominated by the inorganic world (as opposed to our current enviornments which are dominated by the other organisms in it).  Moving to an equivalent environment should not have any negative effect on the survival of the organisms.  At most, it would be the equivalent to one of countless times where a population was split by a receeding ocean or tectonic activity.

Of course, if the "parallel" Earth is different in any way, we'd have to discuss those very specific differences in order to figure out survivability.  Some differences can be handwaved without a second thought.  Other differences (which might seem minute) can be utterly devastating to life as we know it.  Its up to your *precise* parallel Earth as to whether life will survive.

Comment: Yeah I figured that the wormhole itself would be more or less completely speculative - I will use that for the purposes of my story. I wanted to keep it a bit more grounded and maybe have an underground civilization of some kind so that's another possibility. I suppose the level of convergence in evolution would not be as drastic though

Answer (score 4):

The answer is "yes, it could", but this scenario depends on several highly speculative factors:

1. Wormholes do exist, they can be large and provide means of safe travel;
2. "Parallel Earth" has similar conditions at the time, hospitable to ancient organisms;
3. Evolution is convergent, i.e. early prokaryotes should eventually develop into complex organisms, similar to Earth's vertebrates.

Also, if factors #1 and 2 are plausible, then it seems likely that the life on Earth actually came through a similar wormhole (panspermia). In this case tracing whether the life moved from Earth to "parallel Earth", or it was the other way around, and how many other "Earths" are there is becoming virtually impossible.